# CFDataRef to NSData

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am having trouble converting a `CFDataRef` into `NSData` whilst using `ARC`. I am using the `__bridge_transfer` OR `__bridge` cast but it is not working. Could anyone suggest me some other way of casting this two types.
I get the following error

```
Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Incompatible types casting 'CFDataRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFData **') to 'NSData *' with a __bridge cast
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSData *my_nsdata = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)my_cfdata; // -1 on the my_cfdata
```

or

```
NSData *my_nsdata = (__bridge NSData*)my_cfdata; // no adjustment of retain counts.
```

From my blog post here:

http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html

Comment: I dont know why but still I get this error. Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Incompatible types casting 'CFDataRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFData **') to 'NSData *' with a __bridge cast

Comment: ahhh ,i finally got the answer.As clear in the error i am getting,I am using CFDataRef* in place of CFDataRef.Changed that and now it is working